# Removing two adjacent values from a list randomly

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I found the function `pop()`, which will remove a single value from a list. However, I want to remove two values from the list - randomly, but both numbers must be adjacent. For example, in a list of `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, if I randomly picked `2` with `pop()`, I'd also want to remove `1` or `3`.

I need to store the numbers (p and q) for a later calculation, here's my code so far:

```
nlist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
shuffle(nlist)

while nlist:
    p = nlist.pop(random.randrange(len(nlist)))
    #save p and one adjacent value (q) within this loop
    #remove p and q from list
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could choose the `randrange` to be across one less than the list's length, and then pop the same index twice:

```
pop_index = random.randrange(len(nlist)-1)
p = nlist.pop(pop_index)
q = nlist.pop(pop_index)
```

Comment: This looks like it would be great! Except I get an error for "empty range for randrange()". Tried adding some extra parentheses to no avail.

Comment: That could be happening if `len(nlist)` is either 0 or 1. Perhaps change your loop to be `while len(nlist) > 1'? Otherwise, you won't be able to pop two values.

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle some edge cases when removing your elements, namely when the `p` is the first or last element in the list. This uses a handy `random` function, `choice` to determine which adjacent element you choose.

```
while len(nlist) > 1:
    # the number to remove
    p_index = random.randrange(len(nlist))
    if p_index == 0:
        q_index = p_index + 1
    elif p_index == len(nlist) - 1:
        q_index = p_index - 1
    else:
        q_index = p_index + random.choice([-1, 1])
    p, q = nlist[p_index], nlist[q_index]
    nlist.pop(p_index)
    nlist.pop(q_index)
    return p, q
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach:

```
from random import randint
nlist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
data=randint(0,len(nlist)-2)
print([j for i,j in enumerate(nlist) if i not in range(data,data+2)])
```

output:

```
#[3, 4, 5]
#[1, 4, 5]
#[1, 2, 5]
```